# CodeCache initialization. mtCode parameters is passed to new, but mtInternal is used in GrowableArray constructor

Tags: java, c++, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I have some confusion about `CodeCache::_heaps` initialization. The memory type parameter passed to the new allocation function is `mtCode` as can be seen [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/code/codeCache.cpp#l152):

```
GrowableArray<CodeHeap*>* CodeCache::_heaps = 
    new(ResourceObj::C_HEAP, mtCode) GrowableArray<CodeHeap*> (CodeBlobType::All, true);
```

While the `GrowableArray` constructor uses `mtInternal` as the memory type default argument [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/utilities/growableArray.hpp#l170).

```
GrowableArray(int initial_size, bool C_heap = false, MEMFLAGS F = mtInternal)
    : GenericGrowableArray(initial_size, 0, C_heap, F)
```

The thing that I'm confused about is why do we allocate `C_HEAP` memory with `new` using `mtCode` `MEMFLAG,` but `GrowableArray` constructor defaults to `mtInternal` `MEMFLAG`. What is the point of doing so?

Comment: What do you find strange? Seems logical to me. Code Cache structures are allocated with `mtCode` flag, so they will contribute to `Code` section in Native Memory Tracking.

Comment: @apangin So we seem to allocate memory for __pointers__ to the actual code cache (whose memflags are `mtCode`) with memflags `mtInternal`. That's right?

Comment: Yes. Code Cache spaces are mmap'ed as `mtCode`. GrowableArray contains pointers to Code Caches. These pointers are allocated as `mtInternal`. And the pointer to the GrowableArray object itself is allocated as `mtCode`. This `mtInternal` part seems wrong, but it doesn't play much difference - this is just a few bytes.